# How can the velocity of a robot be found if we have VICON coordinates available?

Tags: ros, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have coordinates of the robot available using VICON motion capture system. How can they be used to find the velocity of robot at each instant?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234085/how-can-the-velocity-of-a-robot-be-found-if-we-have-vicon-coordinates-available?/) by [Ros User](https://answers.ros.org/users/26709/ros-user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [donald](https://answers.ros.org/users/24812/donald/) on 2016-05-13**:
Can you specify this a bit? What exactly are you given from the mocap sytstem (position, orientation, timestamp)? Do you want to have the velocity in the robot body frame? I did the same lately for an Optitrack system, so maybe I could give you some hints.

**Comment by [Ros User](https://answers.ros.org/users/26709/ros-user/) on 2016-05-13**:
The system gives x,y,z position of robot's center,orientation of  robot and timestamps(secs).These messages are published at the rate of 100 Hz.As my robot is ground based one,I am using only x and y position(not orientation) to find the velocity. I want to find velocity of the robot's center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One possibility is to use tf's **Transformer::lookupTwist** to calculate the velocity. If you want to do it "by hand" you can compute the current (online) linear velocity expressed in the robot's body frame as:

> v[k] = {o[k-1]}^(-1) * (p[k] - p[k-1]) / (t[k] - t[k-1]),

using the variables

> v[k]: current linear velocity (delayed by 1/200 seconds),

> {o[k-1]}^(-1): previous orientation inverted (unit quaternion or rotation matrix),

> p[k], p[k-1]: positions of this and previous frame,

> t[k], t[k-1]: timestamp of this and previous frame.

This is, you de-rotate the translation vector from the last to the current transform and divide it by the time difference.

The offline version of this is

> v[k] = {o[k]}^(-1) * (p[k+1] - p[k-1]) / (t[k+1] - t[k-1]),

which is the [symmetric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative).

Depending on how well your robot is tracked, the velocity signal might be noisy, so you might want to use a filter.

---

Originally posted by [donald](https://answers.ros.org/users/24812/donald/) with karma: 61 on 2016-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-05-17**:
Note that the lookupTwist function does not currently seem correct ([bug report](https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/43)). I was playing with this function last week and I believe that (at a minimum) @tfoote suggestion needs to be incorporated.

**Comment by [Ros User](https://answers.ros.org/users/26709/ros-user/) on 2016-06-01**:
What is  o[k-1]}^(-1) for? I took every nth  X-Y coordinates, calculated the 2D distance between these two coordinates and divided the distance by the difference in timestamp between the coordinates. It is similar to your approach except o[k-1]}^(-1).

**Comment by [donald](https://answers.ros.org/users/24812/donald/) on 2016-06-06**:
This is the de-rotation. When using it, you will have the robot's velocity in the robot's body frame. Otherwise, your velocity will depend on the orientation of your motion tracking reference frame.